# MFC - Why the pop up message box of DDV_MinMaxUInt only modal for main frame?

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog

we know the pop up message box of DDV_MinMaxUInt is modal. But this message box is only modal for the main frame, NOT for the parent dialog which derived this message box. Where I went wrong?

example: 
Main Frame->Dialog A-> Dialog B -> Dialog C-> DDV_MinMaxUInt(...)
The pop-up message box of DDV_MinMaxUInt is only modal for main frame. But I want this message box modal for all dialog.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I use DDV_MinMaxUInt to valid two different edit box in two different dialog A and B. For dialog A, the pop-up warning message box from DDV_MinMaxUInt is modal, but it is modeless for dialog B. But I have not find any different setting for this two dialog. I want to know the root cause of this issue. Is there a setting flag for this 2 different modal/modeless dialog?

Comment: If you have additional information for your question, please edit your question and don't post it in a comment.

Comment: The popup dialog (which is actually rather a message box) should not be modal, there are no flags to make this message box model or modeless, BTW a modeless message box would be rather useless in this case. You must provide more information about the context, otherwise your answer cannot be answered.

Comment: That validation UI is in fact a message box, and it is (as it should be) **modal**. Please show your dialog's `DoDataExchange()` method.

Comment: Thank you Michael and Vlad. I think I made a mistake for this question. I found that all the pop-up message box is modal, but some of them is only modal for main frame. Please see my re-edited question. Thank you!